# Bootstrap 4 showing Amazon Affiliate ads on different tabs not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've added 6 different "products" that I want to sell on my website. I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core (the latest) and utilizing Twitter Bootstrap 4's tabs.

The first tab shows the content/products just fine (because it's the default, active tab), but when I click on a different tab on my page, none of the content/products show up. I've verified that the Amazon ad link/scripts are in the page source and configured the exact same was as the one that DOES work.

Am I setting this up correctly, or are these ads designed so they cannot be displayed in this type of format?

Here's the website: http://www.wrestlestat.com/shop/main

Here's my cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header pt-2 bold-red-on-black">
                <h2>@Model.Header</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="card-block">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-2" role="tablist">
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#shirts" role="tab">Shirts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#sweatshirts" role="tab">Sweatshirts</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#shoes" role="tab">Shoes</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#headgear" role="tab">Headgear</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#mats" role="tab">Mats</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item">
                                        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#apparel" role="tab">Apparel</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <div class="tab-content">
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="shirts" role="tabpanel">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
                                            amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "wrestlestat-20";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
                                            amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
                                            amzn_assoc_region = "US";
                                            amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "wrestling shirts";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
                                            amzn_assoc_linkid = "1652714d098550932e3244e6b68c660c";
                                        </script>
                                        <script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sweatshirts" role="tabpanel">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
                                            amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "wrestlestat-20";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
                                            amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
                                            amzn_assoc_region = "US";
                                            amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "wrestling sweatshirts";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
                                            amzn_assoc_linkid = "d8fa72ed2145882d2d2b477b692dc3a7";
                                        </script>
                                        <script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="shoes" role="tabpanel">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
                                            amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "wrestlestat-20";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
                                            amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
                                            amzn_assoc_region = "US";
                                            amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "wrestling shoes";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
                                            amzn_assoc_linkid = "64c7df1d0b41ea3f0ec8392345eadbf2";
                                        </script>
                                        <script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="headgear" role="tabpanel">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
                                            amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "wrestlestat-20";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
                                            amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
                                            amzn_assoc_region = "US";
                                            amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "wrestling headgear";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
                                            amzn_assoc_linkid = "50f3bdaf710b4d98ca80ef0fd85ffc89";
                                        </script>
                                        <script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="mats" role="tabpanel">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
                                            amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "wrestlestat-20";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
                                            amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
                                            amzn_assoc_region = "US";
                                            amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "wrestling mats";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
                                            amzn_assoc_linkid = "2b7b352bfa7628a3cdfe070ab4e0c338";
                                        </script>
                                        <script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="apparel" role="tabpanel">
                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                            amzn_assoc_placement = "adunit0";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar = "true";
                                            amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "wrestlestat-20";
                                            amzn_assoc_search_bar_position = "top";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_mode = "search";
                                            amzn_assoc_ad_type = "smart";
                                            amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
                                            amzn_assoc_region = "US";
                                            amzn_assoc_title = "Shop Related Products";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_search_phrase = "wrestling apparel";
                                            amzn_assoc_default_category = "All";
                                            amzn_assoc_linkid = "276b7bc6cbaec842ec7997d866ef94ac";
                                        </script>
                                        <script src="//z-na.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/onejs?MarketPlace=US"></script>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why it is happening. But in my case I did it like.

I added active class to all tabs and after render the tabs. I removed all actives classes **except from actual active tab (in your case, example shirts)**.

its problem with tabs. if they are not active. they dont show data or retrieve. which is weird.

**HTML**

```
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs mt-2" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#shirts" role="tab">Shirts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active remove-after-render" data-toggle="tab" href="#sweatshirts" role="tab">Sweatshirts</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active remove-after-render" data-toggle="tab" href="#shoes" role="tab">Shoes</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active remove-after-render" data-toggle="tab" href="#headgear" role="tab">Headgear</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active remove-after-render" data-toggle="tab" href="#mats" role="tab">Mats</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active remove-after-render" data-toggle="tab" href="#apparel" role="tab">Apparel</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

**JS**

```
  $('.remove-after-render').removeClass('active');
```

One more thing I have noticed in your code. According to Bootstrap active class should be on `li` element not on `a` tag. So try to do same thing on `li` element as well.

wish you all the best.

Comment: Slick! One thing to note, this didn't work until I ALSO added the active class to the actual tab panes....

Comment: Yaa could be because I had this same problem long time ago. But good to know it's solved